# creating local database for reminder in Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

There ia reminder application and there is a need to create a localDatabase table for reminder keep the  enteries into its table. 
how do i create a local database for Reminder Enteries in Windows phone mango?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinQ to Sql to create your database in designer and save it in isolated storage.

[MSDN local database Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

There is an easier way to do it :

[Corrado's Blog](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/corrado/archive/2011/06/05/using-local-database-in-wp7-mango.aspx)

I used this example for my application, and it works like a charm, i copied the whole Linq to Sql dbml into my Wp7 project and it works. Just don't forget to delete or comment out the two unsupported constructors.

Answer (score 0):

http://sterling.codeplex.com/

You can use serling as well to store your Reminder entries.